# Suggestion on "HItlamed" application

Tags: torah-study

I am making a mobile app called "Hitlamed" that will provide the Mishna Torah, Torah, Talmud, Guide for the Perplexed, Nevi'im, Ketuvim, oral Torah and Zohar free of charge in English and Hebrew. It will also have a basic Siddur and information on the 'basics' of Judaism and its concepts written in plain English. The app can be used as a study guide with the ability to create test, discuss concepts and write articles detailing the app's supplied works. A great source of information and study for the convert, Jew trying to return to their roots or advanced scholars or Rabbi's I want it to be simple yet powerful. What suggestions do you think could improve this app?

Comment: Hi @noah and welcome to Mi Yodeya. This sounds like a great endeavour but I am not sure if this is the correct platform to discuss this? Hatzlocho either way!

Comment: Try asking on Frum Software Developer's slack channel.

Comment: Have you seen sefaria.org? I think they beat you to it.